# How to clone a running virtual machine in opennebula 5.x?

Tags: django, python-2.7, xml-rpc, opennebula

I am using XML-RPC to integrate opennebula 5.x. Which methods in xml-rpc doc should I use to clone a VM?

1. Clone a template using template id of running VM using template clone method
2. Template clone and related image will be created.
3. Using the created template id creates a new clone VM using template instantiate method.

Is this the correct solution? What is cloning a running VM?